# Hide Non-Displayed ASP Elements in Design View

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Is there a way to prevent non-displayed elements from appearing in the ASPX Design View editor?

By "non-displayed elements", I mean the background elements (Managers, DataSources, Validators, etc) that show up as grey boxes containing the type and id.

If I have several of those at the top of the page, I can't see much of the preview of my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found it!

Click inside the editor (the Design pane).

View (menu) -> Visual Aids (submenu) -> ASP.NET Non-visual Controls